# Suppress "running out of disk space" Message (per drive) on Windows Server 2003

Tags: disk-space-utilization, windows-server-2003

We have a database server with separate drives for OS, various data files and the transaction log. Our transaction log spills over onto other volumes as well- this is expected behavior.

The problem is that we are constantly getting popups that our transaction log drive is out of space (and that I can free space by deleting old or unnecessary files).

Is there some way to prevent this message from popping up for this particular drive?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, no, not really.

The closest you can probably come is to disable the warning for all drives

> (add the DWORD key "NoLowDiskSpaceChecks" with a value of 1 to /Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/Explorer in a hive--most references on the internet say to put this in HKCU, but I'd probably try putting it in HKLM if you don't want users other than the one currently logged in to keep getting bugged.)

and then set up some analog as close as possible to the same type of warning for the drives you do want to be alerted for. ([This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/177465/can-i-arrange-an-email-to-be-sent-when-a-drive-is-nearly-full) seems to be along the lines of what you would want, and doing things this way has the obvious advantages of a configurable threshold and the ability to set up email alerts rather than simple popups. The answer there pointing to [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324796) in particular seems like it would replicate the functionality of the normal disk space alerts fairly closely if configured with the same values and alert types.)